# Encryption Stored Procedure in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried to create a simple stored procedure in SQL Server to encrypt data with the key.

I have already created a master key `(UserMasterKey)` & a certificate `(UserMasterCert)` in the database. Since that is an one-time task hence did not include in stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AES_ENCRYPT]
    @data VARBINARY,
    @password NVARCHAR(10)
AS
    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY UserMasterKey
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE UserMasterCert WITH PASSWORD = @password;
    DECLARE @encrypted NVARCHAR(50) = ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID(N'UserMasterKey'), @data);
    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY UserMasterKey;
RETURN @encrypted
```

But I get below error:

> Incorrect syntax near @password
>   [SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17759)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong with this Procedure, I have never used Certificates to Encrypt Symmetric keys, as far as I remember we used a Asymmetric key to encrypt the Symmetric keys.

Anyway coming back to your procedure

1. You havent mentioned any length for your `@Data` variable it means by default it gets assigned length of 1. This is sql server's default behaviour.
2. You are trying to return a string from this procedure using return key word. Sql Server can only return INT datatype using RETURN key word. To return any other datatype you have to use OUTPUT parameters.
3. You are trying to store encrypted data to a NVARCHAR variable this data when encrypted is in varbinary datatype.
4. Your Input data would be some string varchar/Nvarchar and output the encrypted data will be varbinary.

**My Suggested Fixes**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AES_ENCRYPT]
    @data       NVARCHAR(50),
    @password   NVARCHAR(10),
    @encrypted  VARBINARY(4000) OUTPUT
AS
 BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY UserMasterKey
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE UserMasterCert WITH PASSWORD = @password;

    SET @encrypted = ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID(N'UserMasterKey'), @data);

    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY UserMasterKey;
 END
```

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive info, but I still encounter same error: `Incorrect syntax near '@password'` sqlfiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17758

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because with your VARBINARY argument you need to specify a length, i.e. VARBINARY(1000) or VARBINARY(MAX).

Comment: I tried putting VARBINARY(MAX)., It did not fix the error:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17760

Comment: Not having a length specified is not an syntax issue. SQL Server will just use the default length, which in this case would be 1.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all of the issues noted by @M.Ali in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23791707/577765), the issue at hand (i.e. the "Incorrect syntax near @password" error) is most likely that the `WITH PASSWORD =` clause requires a literal string and won't accept a variable like you are trying to do with `@password`.

If you look at the MSDN page for [OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190499.aspx) you will the following syntax (redacted to show only the relevant portion):

```
 OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY Key_name DECRYPTION BY <decryption_mechanism>

 <decryption_mechanism> ::=
     CERTIFICATE certificate_name [ WITH PASSWORD = 'password' ]
```

You might be able to get around this limitation via Dynamic SQL. The following is largely based on the code provided by @M.Ali (somewhere on this page ;-) but adapted to place the main code into Dynamic SQL so that it can include the value of `@password` as a string literal and changes the datatype of the `@data` input parameter to be VARBINARY(MAX) to be more inline with the original code provided in the question.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AES_ENCRYPT]
(
    @data       VARBINARY(8000),
    @password   NVARCHAR(10),
    @encrypted  VARBINARY(8000) OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @SQL = N'
    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY UserMasterKey
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE UserMasterCert WITH PASSWORD = '''
      + @password
      + N''';

    SET @TempEncrypted = ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID(N''UserMasterKey''), @TempData);

    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY UserMasterKey;
    ';

    EXEC dbo.sp_executesql
            @SQL,
            N'@TempData VARBINARY(8000), @TempEncrypted VARBINARY(8000) OUTPUT',
            @TempData = @data,
            @TempEncrypted = @encrypted OUTPUT;

END
```